# Intersection of closed and bounded sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ denote a complete metric space. Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of closed and bounded subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property.

> **Question.** Is $\bigcap\mathcal{C}$ necessarily non-empty?

A couple of remarks.

Firstly:

- To see that closedness is necessary, consider the sequence of open intervals $(0,1/n)$ as subsets of the real line.
- To see that boundedness is necessary, consider the sequence of closed intervals $[n,\infty)$ as subsets of the real line.

Secondly: I'm also interested in the converse; that is, whether the above condition  implies completeness. If so, this gives us a notion of completeness for any set $X$ equipped with both a topology and a [bornology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bornological+set).

Comment: I'd start by looking at the closed unit sphere of an infinite dimensional Banach space, and using some counterexample to compactness to get a counterexample.

Comment: As Asaf said, this can't be true, because the (bounded) unit sphere of a real Banach space $X$ is not compact iff $X$ is infinite-dimensional -- but if this property held for all $\mathcal{C}$, it would have to be compact (it's an equivalent def. of compactness). So you don't need to exhibit anything, actually.

Comment: I just posted a question related to the last line of your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3046536/71829

Comment: You may also be interested in my question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047070/71829

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out there's a really easy counter-example. Put a metric space structure on $\mathbb{N}$ by declaring that the distance between any two distinct points is exactly $1$. This is complete, because the only Cauchy-sequences are the constant sequences, which are obviously convergent. Also, every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has diameter at most $1$, and is therefore bounded; further, the induced topology is the discrete topology, so every subset is closed. So in this case, the question reads:

> Does every collection $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with the finite intersection property have non-empty intersection?

Of course, the answer is "no": consider, for example, $$\mathcal{C} = \{[n,\infty)_{\mathbb{N}} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

Comment: The same example works in $\mathbb{R}$ with the complete (!) metric $d(x,y) = \min(|x-y|, 1)$, the truncated standard metric.

Comment: This counterexample has the form of a nested sequence of sets $C_n \supset C_{n+1}$. Somewhat counter-intuitively, if one requires $\operatorname{diam} C_n\to 0$ as an additional hypothesis (i.e., the sets are "small"), then the intersection must be nonempty.

Comment: @6'whitemale, yes. Furthermore I think if we take the original conjecture can replace "the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are bounded" with "the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ have arbitrarily small diameter", it becomes equivalent to completeness.