# When is a bornology on a uniformizable space induced by a uniformity?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space, and let $B$ be a nontrivial [bornology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) on $X$. Sze-Tsen Hu showed in 1949 that $B$ is the collection of bounded sets with respect to some metric for the topology on $X$ if and only if $B$ has a countable [base](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space#Bornological_sets) and for any $S\in B$, there exists a $T\in B$ such that the closure of $S$ is a subset of the interior of $T$.  (See this [journal paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227182103_On_Metric_Boundedness_Structures).)

I’m interested in the analogous result for uniformities.  That is, $X$ be a uniformizable topological space, AKA a completely regular space, and let $B$ be a nontrivial bornology on $X$.  My question is, under what circumstances is $B$ the collection of bounded sets with respect to some uniformity for the topology on $X$.

Note that a subset $A$ of a uniform space is said to be bounded if for each entourage $V$, $A$ is a subset of $V^n[F]$ for some natural number $n$ and some finite set $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this problem was solved by Tom Vroegrijk in this [2009 journal paper](https://polipapers.upv.es/index.php/AGT/article/download/1740/1879), 60 years after the analogous problem for metric spaces was solved.

Let $X$ be a uniformizable topological space, AKA a completely regular space, and let $B$ be a nontrivial bornology on $X$.  Let's call a sequence $(U_n)$ of open sets a bounding sequence if the closure of $U_n$ is a subset of $U_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and every element of $B$ is a subset of some $U_n$.  And let's call a set $S$ saturated if $S$ if for every bounding sequence $(U_n)$, $S$ is a subset of some $U_n$.  Then $B$ is the collection of bounded sets with respect to some uniformity for the topology on $X$ if and only if $B$ contains every saturated set.